# Is two distinct rhumb lines with the same bearing on a perfect sphere parallel?

Tags: 3d, significant-figures

Is two distinct rhumb lines with the same bearing on a perfect sphere parallel?

I am defining parallel as  2 objects as parallel if they do not intersect, go in the same direction, and a constant distance can be defined between the 2.

(Note:  A rhumb line, or loxodrome, is a “line” crossing all meridians at the same angle, i.e. a path of constant bearing. It is obviously easier to manually steer than the constantly changing heading of the shorter great circle route.

I am having a hard time imagining it. How do I show or explain if it would be parallel or not?

Comment: If I remember properly, all rhumb lines that aren't parallels (as in, they have constant latitude, like the equator) go through both poles. So under natural definitions of distances and intersections, rhumb lines are never "parallel". Unless they are parallels (constant latitude).

Comment: Do you mean "don't have a constant latitude?" Because if they are not parallel, they do not have a constant distance.

Comment: On a side note, rhumb lines should only be "easier to steer" if you rely on tools based on longitude/latitude. Assuming your boat is able to go "straight" without being influenced by winds or current (which is unrealistic), it should go along a great circle.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.